# This could be due to the fact that the server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

> {"An error occurred while making the HTTP request to
>   https:xxx/webservice/SOAP/2.0/service. This could be due to the fact
>   that the server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS
>   in the HTTPS case. This could also be caused by a mismatch of the
>   security binding between the client and the server."}

```
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="SitecoreApplicationCenter" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:20:00" sendTimeout="00:05:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
    </binding>
    <binding name="SoapHandlerWSDLBinding">
      <security mode="Transport" />
    </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

–

Error while try to call webservice.

Do I have to add any certificate. If yes,Which one and steps to install

Comment: Please be careful when selecting tags, so you don't select irrelevant tags (like you `c` language tag). Also, don't add code or crucial information in comments, *edit* your question instead. And please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Windows? Is your service self-hosted or are you using IIS?

Comment: Post all information *in the question itself, not the comments*

Comment: Although, most likely the error is caused due to the server's switch to TLS1.2. Which .NET and OS version are you using? The first .NET version to offer TLS1.2 support were 4.5, although it needed configuration. The first version to use it automatically was 4.6.2. *Unsupported* OS versions like 2008 R2 or older require patching and specific registry settings to work with TLS1.2.

Comment: BTW this isn't new. Most if not all service providers abandoned SSL v3 and TLS 1.0 in 2016. Many require nothing less than TLS1.2. That includes Amazon, Azure, Google, banks, airlines, payment services

Comment: I am using Windows 10 and .Net 4.6.2 & IIS. I am facing this issue in my local system itself